# Tableview not updating correctly after adding person

Tags: iphone, tableview

I have to be missing something simple here but it escapes me. After the user enters a new person to a mutable array I want to update the table. The mutable array is the datasource. I believe my issue lies within `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    TextFieldCell *customCell = (TextFieldCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TextCellID"];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        if (customCell == nil) {
            NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TextFieldCell" owner:nil    options:nil];
            for (id currentObject in nibObjects) {
                if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[TextFieldCell class]])
                    customCell = (TextFieldCell *)currentObject;
            }
        }
        customCell.nameTextField.delegate = self;
        cell = customCell;
    }

    else {
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

            cell.textLabel.text = [[self.peopleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1] name];
            NSLog(@"PERSON AT ROW %d = %@", indexPath.row-1, [[self.peopleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1] name]);
            NSLog(@"peopleArray's Size = %d", [self.peopleArray count]);
        }
    }

    return cell; 
}
```

When I first load the view everything is great. This is what prints:

```
PERSON AT ROW 0 = Melissa
peopleArray's Size = 2
PERSON AT ROW 1 = Dave
peopleArray's Size = 2
```

After I add someone to that array I get this:

```
PERSON AT ROW 1 = Dave
peopleArray's Size = 3
PERSON AT ROW 2 = Tom
peopleArray's Size = 3
```

When I add a second person I get:

```
PERSON AT ROW 2 = Tom
peopleArray's Size = 4
PERSON AT ROW 3 = Ralph
peopleArray's Size = 4
```

Why is not printing everyone in the array? This pattern continues and it only ever prints two people, and it's always the last two people. What the heck am I missing?

---**UPDATED**---

Ok. My cells are not updating properly and I figured what I asked advice for was going to help me. I guess that wasn't the main issue.

My issue is that my rows are not printing the proper information. When the view first loads I get:

```
Melissa
Dave
```

but after I add Tom, I get:

```
Melissa         Dave
Melissa    or   Dave
Tom             Tom
```

and after I add Ralph, I get:

```
Melissa          ?
Tom        or    ?
Tom              Tom
Ralph            Ralph
```

What is going on?

Comment: **Tableview not updating correctly**. What do you see in your app when adding new items? You only talked about the `NSLog` output but didn't explain what is the problem on the actual UI.

Comment: I guess the issue is the cells updating properly. When I print `self.peopleArray`, after I add each person, it shows each person. But when it goes to show it in the cells it doesn't show all the names properly.

Comment: See my answer below, does it solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not updating the label of the cells that are reused. You are setting it only once when the cell is newly created. So Change your code into:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [[self.peopleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1] name];
NSLog(@"PERSON AT ROW %d = %@", indexPath.row-1, [[self.peopleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1] name]);
NSLog(@"peopleArray's Size = %d", [self.peopleArray count]);
```

Comment: He obviously did that since the NSLogs are inside cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: No worries, two pair of eyes are always better than one :)

Comment: Looks like I made a new friend!!! Thanks sch. A parenthesis was the culprit. I don't know if I would ever have caught that. Thank you so much. Oh, and now it prints each person and their row, including row 0, each time as opposed to just the "updated ones". Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks. I didn't spot it either the first time :)

Answer (score 1):

You are calling NSLog in the cellForRowAtIndexPath that's why.
The first time it logs everything since the cells are new, but after that the cells remain cached until they go offscreen. Since your table is small, the first cells are always on screen and never recreated. Try to move your NSLog somewhere else if you want to monitor your data source and not the cells (you can see exactly what I mean if you load a large table, scroll it and observe your console)